# How to emulate Taylor and Francis NLM reference style in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

In their template, they post the following customizations.

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\bibpunct[, ]{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% Bibliography support using natbib.sty
\makeatletter% @ becomes a letter
\def\NAT@def@citea{\def\@citea{\NAT@separator}}% Suppress spaces between citations using natbib.sty
\makeatother% @ becomes a symbol again
```

The link for `.bst` file is available in their template ([link](https://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?show=instructions&journalCode=tjms20#formatting-and-templates)). Of course, it is possible to post the script of the file but this is too long. Also, the page shows a pdf file with examples on the style itself.